# Loading X509Certificate results in exception CryptographicException "Cannot find the original signer"

Tags: c#, x509certificate

I am trying to instantiate an `X509Certificate` object, but I keep running into the same `CryptographicException`, with the error message:

> "Cannot find the original signer".

I have tried several ways of loading the certificate:

```
// some different things that I have tried
var cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certFileName);
var cert2 = new X509Certificate(byteArray);
var cert3 = new X509Certificate(byteArray, secretString);
var cert4 = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(certFileName);
```

I have tried both loading from a file and from a byte array. Each time I get the same error. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I was attempting to load just the certificate file, which did not include the private key. To fix the problem, I had to install the private key on the machine on which the certificate was purchased, and then [export it as a .pfx file](https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/ssl-certificates-support/index?page=content&id=SO1532&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US) and move it to where I actually wanted to use it. I'm sure was a newbie mistake. Hopefully, my silly issue will help other newbies in the future.

Comment: Isn't sending the private key through the internet a security leak?

Answer (score 4):

```
        var collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
        collection.Import(byteArray);
        return collection;
```

via https://stackoverflow.com/a/44073265, by https://stackoverflow.com/users/6535399, who writes crypto for msft - e.g. https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/25920

Comment: This is a much better solution.