# C# new X509Certificate2(path) PKCS#7/P7B -> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Cannot find object or property'

Tags: c#, x509certificate2

When trying to create a new certificate from a PKCS#7 (`.p7b`)-file I get the following exception: `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Cannot find object or property'`

I get the same error if I read from file or byte array. I can create `X509Certificate2` with `.pem` or `.p12` files this way without a problem. Why is this happening?

```
new X509Certificate2(path);
new X509Certificate2(byteArray);
```

Comment: In order to import PKCS#7 object you need to use `X509Certificate2Collection.Import` method.

Comment: @Crypt32 Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Cannot find the requested object' exception while creating X509Certificate2 from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44053426/cannot-find-the-requested-object-exception-while-creating-x509certificate2-fro)

Answer (score -1):

we had a similar error and Cryp32's suggestion to use X509Certificate2Collection.Import method worked well. Please mark it as as valid solution to the issue if it worked in your case as well.