# Validate certificate stored in .p7b file using X509Certificate2

Tags: c#, x509certificate

I have a root chain and certificate stored in a single .p7b file that I'd like to authenticate/bind to a Unity environment. I came across Unity's CertificateHandler class https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.CertificateHandler.html and Microsoft's X509Certificates. Using X509Certificate I'd like to validate my certificate like so:

```
    byte[] content = File.ReadAllBytes("servercerts.p7b");
    string contentString = Convert.ToBase64String(content);
    X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(contentString), string.Empty);
```

The Console output in Unity returns the message: `CryptographicException: Input data cannot be coded as a valid certificate.`
I have seen related issues where people have swapped out different parameters for X509Certificate2() though that type of solution has not been helpful in my case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Cannot find the requested object' exception while creating X509Certificate2 from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44053426/cannot-find-the-requested-object-exception-while-creating-x509certificate2-fro)

Comment: If you want to read a P7B as a collection, either use X509Certificate2Collection.Import, or send it to SignedCms.Decode and iterate over the certificates collection on the SignedCms object.   Sending a p7b to the X509Certificate2 constructor does... different things :)

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks though I've tried importing the P7B into a X509Certificate2Collection object but receive the same exception from above