# SSL Certifcate Issue Asp.Net Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, asp.net-web-api, ssl-certificate

I have a Web API which has SSL enabled and when we try to access this webAPI from a .net web application we receive the following error. We are pointing to correct certifcate path as well. Could this be due to incorrect import of cert?

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Cannot find the original signer.
at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromFile(String fileName, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx)
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromFile(String fileName, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.Import(String fileName)
```

Comment: Have you installed the private key on the machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading X509Certificate results in exception CryptographicException "Cannot find the original signer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19190404/loading-x509certificate-results-in-exception-cryptographicexception-cannot-find)